# php md5 algorithm that gives same result as c#

Tags: c#, php, md5

i have a hashing algorithm in C#, in a nutshell, it is:

```
string input = "asd";

System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 alg = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();


byte[] hash = alg.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(input));
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

// outputs:   eBVpbsvxyW5olLd5RW0zDg==
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Now I need to replicate this behaviour in php,

```
$input = "asd";
$output = HashSomething($input);
echo $output;
```

How can I achieve it?

I checked

- md5
- utf8_decode
- utf8_encode
- base64_encode
- base64_decode
- url_decode

but i noted the php md5 doesn't get the == on the end... what am I missing?

*NOTE*: I cannot change C# behaviour because it's already implemented and passwords saved in my db with this algorithm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is PHP's `md5()` function by default returns the hex variation of the hash where C# is returning the raw byte output that must then be made text safe with base64 encoding. If you are running PHP5 you can use `base64_encode(md5('asd', true))`. Notice the second parameter to `md5()` is true which makes `md5()` return the raw bytes instead of the hex.

Comment: The true flag for md5 only exists in PHP5 or higher. In earlier versions you would need to call the pack function.

Answer (score 5):

Did you remember to base64 encode the md5 hash in php?

`$result = base64_encode(md5($password, true));`

The second parameter makes md5 return raw output, which is the same as the functions you're using in C#

Comment: Darn.  You bet me... 
The == is usually from the Base64 encoding, you are doing with Convert.ToBase64String() is that what you are missing?

Comment: Yeah, but how can I achieve it on php? what function should I use?

Answer (score 4):

Your C# code takes the UTF8 bytes from the string; calculates md5 and stores as base64 encoded. So you should do the same in php, which should be:

```
$hashValue = base64_encode(md5(utf8_decode($inputString)))
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like as below for php

```
 php -r "echo base64_encode(md5(utf8_encode('asd'),true));"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...using just md5($myvar) it worked. I am getting the same result C# and PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Gavin Kendall posted helped me. I hope this helps others.

http://jachman.wordpress.com/2006/06/06/md5-hash-keys-with-c/

```
public static string MD5Hash(string text)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text))), “-”, “”);
}
```