# MD5 hashing does not match in C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, md5

I have tried hashing a string in PHP using MD5 and the same in C#, but the results are different.. can someone explain me how to get this matched?

my C# code looks like

```
md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(AuthCode);
            encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

            Guid r = new Guid(encodedBytes);
            string hashString = r.ToString("N");
```

Thanks in advance

Edited: My string is 123 as a string

Outputs;

PHP: 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

C# : 62b92c2059ac5b07964b07152d234b70

Comment: You didn't present us with the string you tried to hash or the php code you tried to use.

Comment: What is your input here?  And what is your equivalent PHP code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821817/php-md5-algorithm-that-gives-same-result-as-c/821846#821846

Comment: I never know you got to write this many lines to get a string md5 hash in c#.... in php its just md5('string'); how simple is that? But no offence to C# coders.... :)

Comment: A single character difference in the string in the two languages will generate completely different hashes. That can be caused by something as simple as one string have a linebreak at the end of it.

Comment: in PHP there is no code for this... its simply md5(string);

Comment: string i used is 123 nothing more or nothing less

Comment: What values are you getting from each?

Comment: @Karthik... i agree mate .....

Comment: @Shawn Mclean, no answer there mate. it shows how to change the PHP code to fit the C# output, but i need the reverse as i cannot change the PHP code. (its not my website)

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? This is a perfect question :|

Comment: @Shawn Mclean, I know i'm a novice in C# but i agree ... this is a real issue for me and i'm sure anyone who tried this will face the same issue ....

Comment: @Shawn: I downvoted this, because at the time, there was no sample input/output, and no PHP code.  Yes, the PHP code is probably just `print md5(AuthCode)`, but it's always better to provide these things in the question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Guid r = new Guid(encodedBytes);
string hashString = r.ToString("N");
```

I'm not sure why you're loading your encoded bytes into a Guid, but that is not the correct way to convert bytes back to a string. Use `BitConverter` instead:

```
string testString = "123";
byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testString);
byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
// hashString == 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Juliet didn't give me the same result as a PHP hash I was comparing against (produced by Magento 1.x), however the following did, based on [this implementation on github](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/4452722):

```
                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    result = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)))
                        .Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
                }
```