# Diffrent result of md5 between php and c#

Tags: c#, php, md5

Hello I trying to convert this part code from php to c# with identical result:

**PHP**:

```
md5("apple", true) //result :8pѕ'OlIігg(•
```

**C#**:

```
    byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("apple");
    byte[] hashedBytes =  MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashedBytes); //result: 8p?'OlI??g(?
```

Similar but not exactly

upd: with  `BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();`
I have got: 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f

And I have not any problems when I use md5("apple", false)

Comment: This helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821677/md5-hashing-does-not-match-in-c-sharp-and-php

Comment: You're printing raw binary garbage, and some of those characters are being mis-interpreted by your output environment. e.g. some of the byte sequences LOOK like multi-byte characters. Your md5 is perfectly fine, it's just an output/display problem.

Comment: Side node: `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` is `IDisposable` and thus should be *disposed*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
 byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
 byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

 var s = Encoding.Default.GetString(hash);
```

or choose another Encoding format.

Comment: I tryid it but unfortunately I did not get the expected result