# Encode in c# to Php Diferent Result

Tags: c#, php, hash, encode

I tried this:

C#

```
Convert.ToBase64String(
    MD5.Create().ComputeHash(
        Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"SALTstring{PasswordBox.Text}")
    )
);
```

PHP

```
$salt = "SALTstring";
$pass = "password";
$suma = $salt . $pass;
*$final = unpack("H*",$suma);*
$junto = implode($final);
$hashed = hash('md5', $junto);
echo $tu = base64_encode($hashed);
```

The result is different in the procedures

**EDIT**

There were some tweaks:

[C string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string):

```
$final = unpack("H*",$suma); >>> $final = unpack("a*",$suma);
```

[Md5 Raw bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/821846/14649377)

```
$hashed = hash('md5', $junto); >>> echo base64_encode(md5($junto, true))
```

Comment: Your problem is almost definitely that `Encoding.Default` isn't [doing what you might expect it to be doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006451/231316).

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the answer, the problem is c# procedure is active in a program and can not change

Comment: For each installation (hopefully you have just one), you'll need to inspect what the default encoding's [CodePage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.codepage?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_CodePage) is, and then reproduce a string to byte array in PHP, [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) should help. During this process, ignore hashing for now, only focus on creating the same byte array from both systems.

Comment: Currently the problem is not in the byte array it is in the md5 hash, the byte array are the same